# FallbackExecutor : No fallback method match found

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-java, spring-cloud-circuitbreaker

Already have a fallback methods with argument as exception but still get error spring6.fallback.FallbackExecutor  : No fallback method match found
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

13:51:19.941  INFO --- o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
13:51:19.946  INFO --- o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
13:51:20.644  WARN --- i.g.r.spring6.fallback.FallbackExecutor  : No fallback method match found

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class com.sapient.graphql.generated.types.User class com.sapient.graphql.component.UserDataResolver.getDefaultUser(class java.lang.String,class java.lang.Throwable)
at io.github.resilience4j.spring6.fallback.FallbackMethod.create(FallbackMethod.java:92) ~[resilience4j-spring6-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at io.github.resilience4j.spring6.fallback.FallbackExecutor.execute(FallbackExecutor.java:31) ~[resilience4j-spring6-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at io.github.resilience4j.spring6.retry.configure.RetryAspect.retryAroundAdvice(RetryAspect.java:117) ~[resilience4j-spring6-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:637) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:71) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at com.sapient.graphql.component.UserDataResolver$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getUserFindById() ~[main/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at com.netflix.graphql.dgs.internal.DataFetcherInvoker.get(DataFetcherInvoker.kt:68) ~[graphql-dgs-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at graphql.schema.DataFetcherFactories.lambda$wrapDataFetcher$2(DataFetcherFactories.java:37) ~[graphql-java-19.5.jar:na]
at graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy.fetchField(ExecutionStrategy.java:282) ~[graphql-java-19.5.jar:na]
at graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy.resolveFieldWithInfo(ExecutionStrategy.java:211) ~[graphql-java-19.5.jar:na]
at graphql.execution.AsyncExecutionStrategy.execute(AsyncExecutionStrategy.java:59) ~[graphql-java-19.5.jar:na]
at graphql.execution.Execution.executeOperation(Execution.java:159) ~[graphql-java-19.5.jar:na]
at graphql.execution.Execution.execute(Execution.java:105) ~[graphql-java-19.5.jar:na]
at graphql.GraphQL.execute(GraphQL.java:645) ~[graphql-java-19.5.jar:na]
at graphql.GraphQL.lambda$parseValidateAndExecute$11(GraphQL.java:564) ~[graphql-java-19.5.jar:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1187) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2309) ~[na:na]
at graphql.GraphQL.parseValidateAndExecute(GraphQL.java:559) ~[graphql-java-19.5.jar:na]
at graphql.GraphQL.executeAsync(GraphQL.java:527) ~[graphql-java-19.5.jar:na]
at com.netflix.graphql.dgs.internal.BaseDgsQueryExecutor.baseExecute(BaseDgsQueryExecutor.kt:127) ~[graphql-dgs-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at com.netflix.graphql.dgs.internal.DefaultDgsQueryExecutor.execute(DefaultDgsQueryExecutor.kt:79) ~[graphql-dgs-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at com.netflix.graphql.dgs.mvc.DgsRestController$graphql$executionResult$1.invoke(DgsRestController.kt:206) ~[graphql-dgs-spring-webmvc-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at com.netflix.graphql.dgs.mvc.DgsRestController$graphql$executionResult$1.invoke(DgsRestController.kt:204) ~[graphql-dgs-spring-webmvc-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at com.netflix.graphql.dgs.internal.utils.TimeTracer.logTime(TimeTracer.kt:24) ~[graphql-dgs-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at com.netflix.graphql.dgs.mvc.DgsRestController.graphql(DgsRestController.kt:204) ~[graphql-dgs-spring-webmvc-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `fallback` method should have the same parameters as the original method, or one more parameter of type Throwable. Example, if your original method is:

```java
@Retry(name = "getUserFindById", fallbackMethod = "getDefaultUser")
public User getUserFindById(String id) {
    // some logic
}
```

Your `fallback` method should like this:

```java
public User getDefaultUser(String id, Throwable ex) {
    // some logic
}
```

Notice that the `fallback` method should also return the same type as the original method. Otherwise `FallbackExecutor` won't be able to find a matching fallback method and throw a `NoSuchMethodException`.

Check out [this link](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#fallback-methods) to learn more about the rules of fallback methods.